# Winform controls reset automatically

Tags: winforms, controls

when I was changing background color of gridview. When I started my app for final tests the buttons were not working. I checked their on click code and it was correct. Then I double clicked the button it created new button onClick_1 method. All controls are now not pointing to the methods existing. They make new methods upon clicking.

Comment: Bro, I created a simple winform app. for example: a button then i double clicked it it generated its onClick method. Now when I got finished and run the app the button wasn't working. So I double clicked it again and it generated a new onClick_1 method. :(

Comment: So eventually all controls I created are not pointing to their methods.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like the `.Designer.cs` file wasn't saved properly or something else weird happened... Try comparing with an older version of the file if you have one and you can at least learn what lines were removed and when.

Comment: :( oh great. Isn't there any easy way to fix this:?

Comment: sounds like a global cut and paste

Comment: :( No I didn't cut/pasted. The last thing I did was changing the gridview background color. And when I ran the app this happened. Non of the  controls are working :(

Comment: @user966614 its trivial thing still. Go to your visual designer, see the events for each control, put it back. I hope you remember the events for a control. In the events section you can scroll to point out the right event.